# How do I add the macd indicator to the chart?

Tags: python, pandas

```
import mplfinance as mpf
import pandas as pd
import yfinance as yf


#Сбор данных
btc = yf.Ticker("ETH-USD").history(period = "1mo", interval = "60m")

mpf.plot(btc,
         type = "renko",
         style = "binance")
```

In this code, a simple renko chart is created, how to add the macd indicator to it so that it is below the chart

I tried to find some training videos and studied the documentation, but I couldn't find anything (